# Como identificar no log de eventos do windows quando uma pasta é deletada?

Tags: windows, vbs, log-de-eventos-windows

Tenho uma aplicação que utiliza uma pasta `c:\temp` no windows e preciso identificar de alguma forma se essa pasta foi deletada para recriar o diretório. Para recriar, tenho em mente usar o agendador de tarefas do windows e usar o disparador de eventos (que utiliza o log de eventos do windows) e a partir de então executar um VBS que irá recriar tal pasta se não existir.

Existe alguma forma de eu identificar essa deleção através do log de eventos do windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arquivos e pastas excluídos são registrados no log do Windows em *"Segurança"* se a auditoria do sistema de arquivos estiver habilitada.

Veja como [aplicar ou modificar configurações de diretiva de auditoria em um arquivo ou pasta local](http://www.cooperati.com.br/2012/04/27/auditoria-no-windows/).

Este outro artigo também pode ser do seu interesse: [Auditoria no Windows](http://www.cooperati.com.br/2012/04/27/auditoria-no-windows/).

Você não explicou por que quer fazer isso, mas seguem algumas sugestões:

- Um aplicativo que precisa gravar em uma pasta ou ler uma pasta deve ele mesmo verificar a existência dela antes, e ele mesmo pode criar a pasta - não precisa depender de um agente externo para isso.
- Um aplicativo não deveria usar a pasta *c:\temp*. O Windows oferece API para manipular pasta temporária ou de dados do usuário no local adequado, abaixo de `C:\Users\user_name`. O modo de usar esta API varia de acordo com a sua linguagem de programação.

Em `VBS`, por exemplo:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const TemporaryFolder = 2
Set tfolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)

msgbox tfolder
```

Este código mostrará `C:\Users\nome_usuario\AppData\Local\Temp`, que é o local adequado para um aplicativo gravar e ler arquivos temporários.

Comment: Meu problema é porque tenho 2 programas, sendo que 1 deles deleta a pasta temp e outro usa essa pasta. Não desenvolvi esses programas e um deles já não têm suporte. A solução que pensei seria recriar essa pasta assim que ela for deletada, portanto cheguei na pergunta acima.

Comment: @LeandroLUK Entendo. E a auditoria do sistema de arquivos, é isso que você estava procurando?

Comment: Estava lendo aqui, acho que isso me ajuda, assim posso criar uma tarefa agendada usando o evento da auditoria... vou testar aqui parceiro, muito obrigado

Comment: @LeandroLUK Outra coisa é que, dependendo do tempo de resposta que você precisa à deleção da pasta, talvez nem precise disparar a criação dela a partir do evento de exclusão, mas simplesmente agende o VBS para que ele mesmo verifique e crie (tipo, a cada 1 minuto).

Comment: sim mas se eu colocar pra ele fazer isso, é um "serviço" a mais para execução, e como o computador que tem essas aplicações é da era das cavernas, tenho que evitar processamento desnecessário rs